# Remove-AzureRmRouteConfig doesn't work with where-object the same way Get-AzureRmRouteConfig does

Tags: azure, powershell

```
Get-AzureRmRouteConfig -RouteTable $rt | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*virginia*"}
```

Gets all of the route configs with the names as expected. For instance, usgovvirginia_1

```
Remove-AzureRmRouteConfig -RouteTable $rt | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*virginia*"}
```

Gives this error

```
Remove-AzureRmRouteConfig : Sequence contains no matching element
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureRmRouteConfig -RouteTable $rt | Where-Object {$_.Name -li ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureRmRouteConfig], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.RemoveAzureRmRouteConfigCommand
```

I've been trying to work with Route table with PowerShell, so I would like to understand why this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because piping works left to right, i.e. output of the command from left feeds into the next one on right.

In your case, you're trying to remove the route before selecting it.

Try something like code below (also notice the Set-AzureRmRouteTable in the end, because your changes won't be applied unless you do the Set command in the end)

```
$rt = Get-AzureRmRouteTable -ResourceGroupName "your route table - resource group name"

Get-AzureRmRouteConfig -RouteTable $rt | where-object {$_.Name -like "*virginia*"} | ForEach-Object
 {Remove-AzureRmRouteConfig -RouteTable $rt -Name $_.Name | Set-AzureRmRouteTable}
```

you can look at an example on Microsoft docs as well - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/remove-azurermrouteconfig?view=azurermps-6.7.0

In your first command, you get the routes first and then select specific ones matching a pattern/apply filter on top of the routes so it works fine.

```
Get-AzureRmRouteConfig -RouteTable $rt | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*virginia*"}
```

In your second command, you try to remove the route first and then select specific ones matching a pattern/apply filter on top, so it fails

```
Remove-AzureRmRouteConfig -RouteTable $rt | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*virginia*"}
```